# Joomla articles and modules not showing on small screens

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I'm really quite new to Joomla and I've encountered a problem. On my homepage the article is showing just fine, but all the other modules (except for the menu bar) disappear when I switch to a smaller screen size. On my other pages the article doesn't even show anymore, just the menu bar. I'm using the purity III template. I have no idea what's going on since the settings in the layout of the template indicate that all modules that are showing on a desktop should also be displayed on a mobile device, and I've found no difference in settings in the articles itself. [My site](http://www.dolfijnenlier.be).

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the responsive design hides them on purpose.

Just from a quick peek at your code using inspect element I can see that the class "slideshow hidden-xs" gets a display:none on smaller screen sizes and all of your main content is wrapped in that element. If all of your content is not supposed to be wrapped in that element (which I'm guessing it's not) you're most likely missing a closing tag on a div or something.

Find the missing closing tag (ie: /div, /a, etc) and it will probably solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that totally solved the problem! I forgot a div closing tag.

Answer (score -1):

You can update the latest version of Joomla and check again that some problem is coming or not. I yes then download new theme for your website which is compatible with your theme.